# CSS not applied properly after VueJS build

Tags: html, css, vue.js, bulma

I am using Vue v2.5.

I have the following code, and the image has a max-height of 4rem.

```js
<template>
  <div class="main">
    <b-navbar class="main-navbar">
      <template slot="brand">
        <b-navbar-item tag="router-link" :to="{ path: '/' }">
          <img
            src="static/images/GOOD.png"
            alt="Lightweight UI components for Vue.js based on Bulma"
          >
        </b-navbar-item>
      </template>
  </div>
</template>

...
<style scope>
  .navbar-item img {
    max-height: 4rem;
    padding: .3rem .75rem;
  }
</style>
```

However, if you access the built index.html using express after building with cli built-in webpack, it will come out as 1.75rem.

I have 1.75rem not declared anywhere.

And besides that, there are many differences from running in vue-cli dev mode.

What could be the problem?

Comment: should be `scoped` not `scope`

Comment: Yes, and since when Vue builds projects it combines files together, without `scoped` the styles could be overridden. You could also try using `!important`.